# Load only one section from a YAML config file

Tags: go, yaml, configuration-files

I have multiple components that each of them needs to load specific definitions for it to run, I want to make one big YAML file divided into sections, that each section will belong to a different component.

So instead of having 4 config files for 4 components I'll have one big config file that divided into sections.

Now I want to load on each component just the relvant section from the yaml config file.

Can I do it? and how?

Update:

Both answers have satisfied me (embedded YAML files in one YAML file and the other answer was to unmarshal the JSON to an object that contains only the relevant section I'm interstring in).

Comment: First of all: can you show your code and indicate what YAML library you're using? There's no YAML parser in the stdlib so I assume you have some 3rd party lib. That said, most work the same as `encoding/json`, so you can define a type that only has the section you want, unmarshal into it, and you'll only have that section; rinse and repeat for as many sections as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML specification allows to have multiple YAML documents in one file by delimiting them with `---`: http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395

You would have to check how the library you're utilizing handles this.